# How to filter my Firebase stream using orWhere method for multiple fields of document in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter my stream based on conditions on two fields and I want to fetch the document even if it matches the condition of one field only, how to do that in Flutter? Code example:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> myStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('myCollection')
    .where('field1', isEqualTo: 'value1')
    .orWhere('field2', isEqualTo: 'value1')
    .snapshots();
```

(There is no such orWhere method in flutter).
I dont want to filter the data myself after fetching all the documents.

Comment: There is a feature in preview status to support OR queries, [check here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries). Flutter code snippet is not provided yet.

Answer (score 1):

That query should looks something lke this:

```
var query = db.collection("myCollection").where(
  Filter.or(
    Filter("field1", isEqualTo: "value1"),
    Filter("field2", isEqualTo: "value1"),
  )
);
Stream<QuerySnapshot> myStream = query.snapshots();
```

Comment: If this is the syntax in Flutter it would be nice to add it to the official documentation.